# How to remove squished oil-filter on Nissan NP200/Renault Sandero

Tags: oil-filter

I just broke an oil-filter wrench, attempting to loosen the oil filter.

It's a really tight space, to begin with, but the filter is on real tight, too.

So now it is squished and still on tight.

How do I remove this oil-filter, now?

Do I need to apply heat? Is it safe to do? I can't run the engine since there is no new oil in yet(I wanted to change the filter before putting new oil in)

Comment: Have you used a good squirt of penetrating oil?

Comment: Never thought to try that, tbh, but it's off now. Next time will bear that in mind.

Comment: How did you do it, the screwdriver method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drive a thick, heavy Phillips screwdriver completely through the oil filter from side to side using a hammer, midway down, then use the screwdriver for leverage to twist the filter off.

It may be a little less messy if you first puncture the lowest point on the oil filter and allow it to drain.

Do not use a flame to heat the oil filter. A hot air gun close to the top of the filter wouldn't hurt.

Comment: This method was successful. See Jim's comments under HandyHowie's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The seam on the base of the filter is probably the strongest part of the filter.  If you can get to it, use a cold chisel and hammer to tap the on the edge of the seam to try to turn the filter to undo it.

Hammering a screwdriver through the filter can end up ripping the filter and will case a big mess.  I would use that as a last resort.

Comment: Good idea! If it's not possible to swing a hammer in the limited space and if the OP has or can borrow a pneumatic hammer with a flattened chisel tip, that would serve as well on the base rim of the filter.

Comment: Right... this is a renault, and the filter was very tricky to get to without labor-intensive removal of obstacles. I eventually managed to drive through with a hammer, but it took several screw-drivers of varynig sizes and 3 holes later it was turning loose. What a mission. And yes it was messy, but access meant there was no other way. Lord knows how I'm going to tighten the new one on.

Comment: I also had to exercise a bit of caution because turning the remainder off by hand meant I came into contact with jagged aluminium.

Comment: @Jim Glad it worked out for you. Be sure to oil the new gasket before you install the new filter if you haven't been doing so. Maybe it won't stick so hard next time.

Comment: No, it wasn't me, but yes, that was probably the cause of the sticking.